# How to tell if you are in your own constructor, or your base class's constructor in c#

Tags: c#, reflection

If a class Sub is calling its base class Super's constructor, is there a way to tell that it is not just a call to Super's constructor alone?

I am loading in data from the disk into objects, and I would like to verify that all fields are not null using reflection. However, if I am calling my base constructor, then it isn't appropriate to check this until all constructors are finished. Example:

```
class Super
{
    string s;
    float? f;
    public Super(List<string> lines)
    {
        //initialize s and f based on lines

        if (notFromSubclassConstructor))
        { 
            AssertInitialized(this);
        }
    }

    public static void AssertInitialized(Super super)
    {
        // Iterate through every field and make sure it isnt null
        // I already know how to do this part. If we find a null
        // field we throw an exception.
    }
}

class Sub : Super
{
    string something;
    int? somethingElse;
    public Sub(List<string> lines)
        : base(lines) //we dont want to AssertInitialized inside here, we arent done yet!
    {
        //initialize blah blah

        if (notFromSubclassConstructor))
        { 
            AssertInitialized(this);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid passing some sort of boolean indicating where I'm coming from since that's ugly. Can I do this somehow with reflection or by other means? Feel free to suggest alternative paradigms too.

Comment: Reflection will be much slower than using a boolean.

Comment: If this needs to happen last, then just put it at the end of the original class's constructor and in all child constructors call base() last.

Comment: @Steve how would i use a boolean to check every field? The advantage here is that i can have any nullable field and not need to change any of the verifying code.

Comment: @steve oh I see what you are saying. The bottleneck here is disk I/O though, so that is not important.

Comment: Can you share your logic on how to initialize your fields based on the string lines? How do you know what field to initialize based on the string? Is it based on a predetermined order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just have each class in the hierarchy check its own fields.  If an exception is thrown in the base class constructor, the derived class constructor will never run, as the exception will propagate to the caller directly.

This allows each class to be responsible for its own data, which should be more maintainable over time.  (It also allows you to check the initialization directly instead of trying to rely on reflection, which is not only faster, but simpler to use and write.)

Answer (score 7):

Well you *could* use:

```
if (GetType() == typeof(Super))
```

That will determine the actual type of the object.

But really I'm not at all sure about this pattern anyway. Why not make `Super.AssertInitialized` just check the fields in `Super`, and `Sub.AssertInitialized` check the fields in `Sub`? Make them both private methods, and call them from both constructors.

EDIT: Just to be clear, I would make the checks explicitly use the relevant fields - don't iterate using reflection here - you know what all the fields are, so why not use them?

Comment: IMO as Steve mentioned in his comment using Boolean is better than reflection, in this case reflection can cause to spaghetti coding.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: Yes, I was trying to get at that with my later paragraph. Will edit to clarify.

Comment: @JonSkeet The reason I don't just check the fields is because I want to be able to add/remove fields without changing any of the checking code.

Comment: @MSmith: Do you find yourself adding and removing fields that often? It *should* impact significant amounts of code, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Well, or add your data consistency control in top most class in your hierarchy, or add a `Factory`, that constructs your object, and checks its data. IMHO are most "clear" solutions.